# ValueError: Found Inconsistent Number of Samples[1691, 725]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried developing a machine learning model based on stock data but I keep getting the "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1691,725] [Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QF7A.png)

```py
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the data but I can't be sure.

EDIT: Thanks for the help everyone who commented.

Comment: We don't need all teh code, just post your full stacktrace: whwat was the offending line? Was it the `train_test_split()` line, the `LinearRegression() fit`, the `.score()` or what? Post the stacktrace and that line.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x_train` and `y_train` are of different lengths(size) might have been some mistake while declaring them.